# How to extract drivers from windows 8.1 installation?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, drivers

Is it possible to somehow extract drivers from a PC running windows 8 so that I can use/install the same drivers on a new installation?

I'm running windows 8.1 on a Dell Inspiron n5010 laptop.
There is no installation disk and the drivers available on the dell website work only on windows 7, Windows XP or Linux. Specifically the drivers i need are for the WiFi and Ethernet adapters. I connected to the internet by tethering my 3G data enabled phone to the laptop and windows tried to look for drivers online but to no avail. However one day, without any warning, windows somehow managed to install drivers for Ethernet and WiFi all on it's own!

Now i want to save these drivers so that I can use them again if I ever choose to reinstall Windows 8.1. (I'm considering trying out Windows 10)

Comment: Windows should find the latest drivers automatically for Wifi & Ethernet honestly.

Comment: Dell offers at least window7 drivers: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-intel-n5010/drivers the rest should be automatically dwnloaded via WindowsUpdate

Comment: Except it did not do so in this case. I was stuck without any Ethernet or WiFi for months before it somehow finally found some drivers. It's why I'm looking for a solution other that what Windows does on its own. Dell does not support newer drivers for my laptop either and windows 7 drivers apparently do not work on windows 8 or above.

Comment: Did you try the Windows 7 drivers? In my experience the Win7 drivers have worked for 8 and 8.1.

Comment: I quote my own comment "windows 7 drivers apparently do not work on windows 8 or above." win 7 drivers were the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup your **Inf** and **Drivers** folder from your current installation (eg. C:\Windows\Inf*.*)

PS: If you have enough space, backup your entire windows folder and after the reinstall look for your drivers in the backup

Comment: Ok this sounds good in theory. I'll try it out and tell if it works.

Comment: this helped me a lot of times, i've updated the driver from the old instalation

Comment: try Free Driver Backup http://www.freedriverbackup.com/download/index.php